# Javascript is not working but there is no errors

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code and it seems like totally OK, I can't see any errors there, but it is still not working.

Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/a3dhuon4/

```
var map;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var map_center;
var map_zoom;

//initialize Google Map API onload
$(function() {
    initialize();
});


//calls to make after finishing complete page load
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.typecar').on('click', function() {
            $('.typecar.selected_car').removeClass('selected_car');
            $(this).toggleClass('selected_car');
        })
        //call on form submit
    $("#dirform").submit(function() {
        var type_auto = $('.typecar.selected_car').attr('data-car');
        if (type_auto) {
            $('#errors').text('');
            $("#loader").html('&nbsp;<span class="label label-info">Loading...</span>');
            calcRoute(type_auto);
        } else {
            $('#errors').text('Choose type of transport');
        }
        return false;
    });

    // Hack for loading Map properly when opened from Modal box
    $('#mapModal').on('shown', function() {
        map_center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

        map.setCenter(map_center);
        map.setZoom(map_zoom);
    });

    $('#TransferOrder').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dir = $('#dirform').serialize();
        var data = $(this).serialize() +'&carType='+$('.selected_car').attr('data-car') +'&total=' + $('#summary').text() + ' euro&' + dir;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://begosolution.com/EngineTest/proxysender.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#formdiv').slideUp();
            }
        })
    })

});


// Initialize google map object
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.909400, 24.205558),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    apply_autocomplete($("#fromAddress")[0]);
    apply_autocomplete($("#toAddress")[0]);
}

// Apply Autocomplete API
function apply_autocomplete(input) {
    var options = {
        types: ['geocode']
    };
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
}


// Calculate route and directions
function calcRoute(type_auto) {
    //create waypoints array & fill it with all locations entered by user
    var waypts = new Array();

    var start_address = $("#fromAddress").val();
    var end_address = $("#toAddress").val();


    $('input[name="toWaypoints[]"]').each(function() {
        waypts.push({
            location: $(this).val(),
            stopover: true
        });
    });

    // Create a Request variable for Map
    var request = {
        origin: start_address,
        destination: end_address,
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    // Execute the Route Method to generate Direction Route on Map
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        //var directionsDiv = document.getElementById('directions');
        var think = false;
        var loc_arr = [];
        if (response.status === 'OK') {
            var mapData = response.routes[0].legs;
        } else {
            var reserror = true;
        }
        // list of objects
        var Tallin = { in : {
                standart: 17,
                minivan: 18,
                minibus: 19
            },
            out: {
                In: 35,
                standart: 0.45,
                minivan: 0.55,
                minibus: 0.65
            }
        }
        var Riga = {
            airport: {
                standart: 25,
                minivan: 32,
                minibus: 36
            },
            in : {
                standart: 22,
                minivan: 29,
                minibus: 33
            },
            out: {
                In: 35,
                standart: 0.45,
                minivan: 0.55,
                minibus: 0.65
            }
        }
        var Helsinki = {
            airport: {
                standart: 39,
                minivan: 49,
                minibus: 59
            },
            in : {
                standart: 33,
                minivan: 43,
                minibus: 53
            },
            out: {
                In: 35,
                standart: 0.8,
                minivan: 0.95,
                minibus: 1.10
            }
        }

        var lat_c = ['latvijas', 'Р»Р°С‚РІРёСЏ', 'latvia'];
        var riga_c = ['rД«ga', 'riga', 'СЂРёРіР°'];
        var riga_airport = ['lv-1053'];
        var est_c = ['СЌСЃС‚РѕРЅРёСЏ', 'estonia', 'eesti'];
        var tal_c = ['tallinna', 'tallinn', 'С‚Р°Р»Р»РёРЅ'];
        var fin_c = ['С„РёРЅР»СЏРЅРґРёСЏ', 'finland', 'finlandia'];
        var hel_c = ['helsinki', 'helsingfors', 'vantaa', 'vanda', 'espoo', 'esbo', 'С…РµР»СЊСЃРёРЅРєРё', 'СЌСЃРїРѕ', 'РІР°РЅС‚Р°Р°'];
        var hel_airport = ['01530', '01531'];
        var rus_c = ['СЂРѕСЃСЃРёСЏ', 'russia', 'rus'];
        var spb_c = ['СЃР°РЅРєС‚-РїРµС‚РµСЂР±СѓСЂРі', 'st petersburg', 'st.petersburg', 'st.petersburg'];
        var spb_lenobl = ['Р»РµРЅРёРЅРіСЂР°РґСЃРєР°СЏ РѕР±Р».'];


        var mat = 0;

        function checkcountry(countryStart, countryEnd) {
            var c_arr = [lat_c, est_c, fin_c, rus_c];
            for (var p = 0; p < c_arr.length; p++) {
                if (c_arr[p].indexOf(countryStart) > -1) {
                    mat++
                }
                if (c_arr[p].indexOf(countryEnd) > -1) {
                    mat++
                }
            }
        }


        if (!reserror) {
            for (var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++) {
                loc_arr.push({ 'startLoc': mapData[i].start_address.split(','), 'endLoc': mapData[i].end_address.split(',') });
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < loc_arr.length; i++) {
                checkcountry(loc_arr[i].endLoc[loc_arr[i].endLoc.length - 1].trim().toLowerCase(), loc_arr[i].startLoc[loc_arr[i].startLoc.length - 1].trim().toLowerCase());
                console.log(loc_arr[i]);
                if (loc_arr[i].endLoc[loc_arr[i].endLoc.length - 1] == loc_arr[i].startLoc[loc_arr[i].startLoc.length - 1]) {
                    var country = loc_arr[i].endLoc[loc_arr[i].endLoc.length - 1].trim().toLowerCase();
                    if (lat_c.indexOf(country) > -1) { //Р›Р°С‚РІРёСЏ
                        try {
                            var loc_end_city = loc_arr[i].endLoc[2].toLowerCase().trim();
                        } catch (e) {
                            var loc_end_city = loc_arr[i].endLoc[0].toLowerCase().trim();
                        }
                        try {
                            var loc_start_city = loc_arr[i].startLoc[2].toLowerCase().trim();
                        } catch (e) {
                            var loc_start_city = loc_arr[i].startLoc[0].toLowerCase().trim();
                        }
                        if ((riga_c.indexOf(loc_end_city) > -1) || (riga_c.indexOf(loc_start_city) > -1)) { //Р РёРіР°
                            if ((riga_c.indexOf(loc_end_city) > -1) && (riga_c.indexOf(loc_start_city) > -1)) {
                                var COST = Riga.in[type_auto];
                            } else {
                                if ((riga_airport.indexOf(loc_arr[i].endLoc[loc_arr[i].endLoc.length - 2].toLowerCase().trim()) > -1) || (riga_airport.indexOf(loc_arr[i].startLoc[loc_arr[i].startLoc.length - 2].toLowerCase().trim()) > -1)) {
                                    var COST = Riga.out.In;
                                    var COSTOFLENGTH = Riga.out[type_auto];
                                } else {
                                    var COST = Riga.out.In;
                                    var COSTOFLENGTH = Riga.out[type_auto];
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            if ((riga_airport.indexOf(loc_arr[i].endLoc[loc_arr[i].endLoc.length - 2].trim()) > -1) || (riga_airport.indexOf(loc_arr[i].startLoc[loc_arr[i].startLoc.length - 2].trim()) > -1)) {
                                var COST = Riga.out.In;
                                var COSTOFLENGTH = Riga.out[type_auto];
                            } else {
                                var MSG = 'Price on request';
                                think = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (est_c.indexOf(country) > -1) { //Р­СЃС‚РѕРЅРёСЏ
                        try {
                            var loc_end_city = loc_arr[i].endLoc[loc_arr[i].endLoc.length - 2].replace(/[\d\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase();
                        } catch (e) {
                            var loc_end_city = loc_arr[i].endLoc[0].toLowerCase().trim();
                        }
                        try {
                            var loc_start_city = loc_arr[i].startLoc[loc_arr[i].startLoc.length - 2].replace(/[\d\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase();
                        } catch (e) {
                            var loc_start_city = loc_arr[i].startLoc[0].toLowerCase().trim();
                        }
                        if ((tal_c.indexOf(loc_end_city) > -1) || (tal_c.indexOf(loc_start_city) > -1)) { //РўР°Р»Р»РёРЅ
                            if ((tal_c.indexOf(loc_end_city) > -1) && (tal_c.indexOf(loc_start_city) > -1)) {
                                var COST = Tallin.in[type_auto];
                            } else {
                                var COST = Tallin.out.In;
                                var COSTOFLENGTH = Tallin.out[type_auto];
                            }
                        } else {
                            var MSG = 'Price on request';
                            think = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (fin_c.indexOf(country) > -1) {
                        try {
                            var loc_end_city = loc_arr[i].endLoc[loc_arr[i].endLoc.length - 2].replace(/[\d\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase();
                        } catch (e) {
                            var loc_end_city = loc_arr[i].endLoc[0].toLowerCase().trim();
                        }
                        try {
                            var loc_start_city = loc_arr[i].startLoc[loc_arr[i].startLoc.length - 2].replace(/[\d\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase();
                        } catch (e) {
                            var loc_start_city = loc_arr[i].startLoc[0].toLowerCase().trim();
                        }
                        if ((hel_c.indexOf(loc_end_city) > -1) || (hel_c.indexOf(loc_start_city) > -1)) {
                            if ((hel_c.indexOf(loc_end_city) > -1) && (hel_c.indexOf(loc_start_city) > -1)) {
                                if ((hel_airport.indexOf(loc_arr[i].endLoc[loc_arr[i].endLoc.length - 2].replace(/[\D\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase()) > -1) || (hel_airport.indexOf(loc_arr[i].startLoc[loc_arr[i].startLoc.length - 2].replace(/[\D\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase()) > -1)) { ////РҐРµР»СЊСЃРёРЅРєРё Р°СЌСЂРѕРїРѕСЂС‚
                                    var COST = Helsinki.airport[type_auto];
                                } else {
                                    var COST = Helsinki.in[type_auto];
                                }
                            } else {
                                if ((hel_airport.indexOf(loc_arr[i].endLoc[loc_arr[i].endLoc.length - 2].replace(/[\D\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase()) > -1) || (hel_airport.indexOf(loc_arr[i].startLoc[loc_arr[i].startLoc.length - 2].replace(/[\D\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase()) > -1)) { ////РҐРµР»СЊСЃРёРЅРєРё Р°СЌСЂРѕРїРѕСЂС‚
                                    var COST = Helsinki.out.In;
                                    var COSTOFLENGTH = Helsinki.out[type_auto];
                                    //РџРѕСЃС‚Р°РІРёС‚СЊ СЃС‚РѕРёРјРѕСЃС‚СЊ Р°СЌСЂРѕРїРѕСЂС‚Р°
                                } else {
                                    var COST = Helsinki.out.In;
                                    var COSTOFLENGTH = Helsinki.out[type_auto];
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            var MSG = 'Price on request';
                            think = true;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    var countryStart = loc_arr[i].startLoc[loc_arr[i].startLoc.length - 1].toLowerCase().trim();
                    var countryEnd = loc_arr[i].endLoc[loc_arr[i].endLoc.length - 1].toLowerCase().trim();
                    if ((rus_c.indexOf(countryStart) > -1) || (rus_c.indexOf(countryEnd) > -1)) {
                        if ((spb_c.indexOf(loc_arr[i].startLoc[Math.ceil(loc_arr[i].startLoc.length / 2 - 1)].toLowerCase().trim()) > -1) || (spb_c.indexOf(loc_arr[i].endLoc[Math.ceil(loc_arr[i].endLoc.length / 2 - 1)].toLowerCase().trim()) > -1) || (spb_lenobl.indexOf(loc_arr[i].startLoc[Math.ceil(loc_arr[i].startLoc.length / 2 - 1)].toLowerCase().trim()) > -1) || (spb_lenobl.indexOf(loc_arr[i].endLoc[Math.ceil(loc_arr[i].endLoc.length / 2 - 1)].toLowerCase().trim()) > -1)) {
                            try {
                                var flag = (riga_c.indexOf(loc_arr[i].endLoc[2].toLowerCase().trim()) > -1) || (riga_c.indexOf(loc_arr[i].startLoc[2].toLowerCase().trim()) > -1);
                                try {
                                    var flagair = (riga_airport.indexOf(loc_arr[i].endLoc[3].toLowerCase().trim()) > -1);
                                } catch (e) {
                                    var flagair = false;
                                }
                                try {
                                    var flagair = (riga_airport.indexOf(loc_arr[i].startLoc[3].toLowerCase().trim()) > -1);
                                } catch (e) {
                                    var flagair = false;
                                }
                            } catch (e) {
                                var flag = (riga_c.indexOf(loc_arr[i].endLoc[0].toLowerCase().trim()) > -1) || (riga_c.indexOf(loc_arr[i].startLoc[0].toLowerCase().trim()) > -1);
                            }
                            if (flag || flagair) { //Р РёРіР°
                                var COST = Riga.out.In;
                                var COSTOFLENGTH = Riga.out[type_auto];
                            }
                            try {
                                var flag = (tal_c.indexOf(loc_arr[i].endLoc[loc_arr[i].endLoc.length - 2].replace(/[\d\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase()) > -1) || ((tal_c.indexOf(loc_arr[i].startLoc[loc_arr[i].startLoc.length - 2].replace(/[\d\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase())) > -1);
                            } catch (e) {
                                var flag = (tal_c.indexOf(loc_arr[i].endLoc[0].replace(/[\d\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase()) > -1) || ((tal_c.indexOf(loc_arr[i].startLoc[0].replace(/[\d\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase())) > -1);
                            }
                            if (flag) { //РўР°Р»Р»РёРЅ
                                var COST = Tallin.out.In;
                                var COSTOFLENGTH = Tallin.out[type_auto];
                            }
                            try {
                                var flag = (hel_c.indexOf(loc_arr[i].endLoc[loc_arr[i].endLoc.length - 2].replace(/[\d\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase()) > -1) || (hel_c.indexOf(loc_arr[i].startLoc[loc_arr[i].startLoc.length - 2].replace(/[\d\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase()) > -1);
                            } catch (e) {
                                var flag = (hel_c.indexOf(loc_arr[i].endLoc[0].replace(/[\d\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase()) > -1) || (hel_c.indexOf(loc_arr[i].startLoc[0].replace(/[\d\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase()) > -1);
                            }
                            if (flag) { //РҐРµР»СЊСЃРёРЅРєРё
                                var COST = Helsinki.out.In;
                                var COSTOFLENGTH = Helsinki.out[type_auto];
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((fin_c.indexOf(countryEnd) > -1) || (fin_c.indexOf(countryStart) > -1)) {
                        var MSG = 'Unfortunately, this transfer is not possible';
                    } else {
                        var loc_end_city = loc_arr[i].endLoc[loc_arr[i].endLoc.length - 2].replace(/[\d\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase();
                        var loc_start_city = loc_arr[i].startLoc[loc_arr[i].startLoc.length - 2].replace(/[\d\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase();
                        if ((tal_c.indexOf(loc_start_city) > -1)) {
                            var COST = Tallin.out.In;
                            var COSTOFLENGTH = Tallin.out[type_auto];
                        } else if (riga_c.indexOf(loc_start_city) > -1) {
                            var COST = Riga.out.In;
                            var COSTOFLENGTH = Riga.out[type_auto];
                        } else {
                            var MSG = 'Price on request';
                            think = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            //directionsDiv.innerHTML = "";
            console.log(typeof(MSG), typeof(COST), think);
            if (mat<2) {
                initialize();
                $('#formdiv').fadeOut();
                $("#loader").html('');
                $("#locations").html('');
                $("#summary").html('');
                return false;
            }
            $('#formdiv').fadeIn();

            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            //directionsDisplay.setPanel(directionsDiv);
            var route = response.routes[0];

            // calculate total distance and duration
            // generate list of locations to print
            var distance = 0;
            var time = 0;
            var locations_list = '<ol>';
            for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                var theLeg = route.legs[i];
                locations_list += '<li>' + theLeg.start_address + '</li>';
                distance += theLeg.distance.value;
                time += theLeg.duration.value;
            }
            locations_list += '<li>' + theLeg.end_address + '</li>';
            locations_list += '</ol>';

            $("#locations").html('<h4>Directions for :</h4>' + locations_list);


            //display summary into summary block
            total_summary = '<div class="alert alert-success">';
            if (COSTOFLENGTH) {
                var summary_cost = (COST + (Math.round(distance / 100) / 10 * COSTOFLENGTH)).toFixed(2);
                total_summary += '  <strong>Total Distance : </strong>' + showDistance(distance) + " ( about " + Math.round(time / 60) + " minutes) " + "<i class='fa fa-eur' aria-hidden='true'></i> " + summary_cost;
            } else if (COST) {
                total_summary += '  <strong>Total Distance : </strong>' + showDistance(distance) + " ( about " + Math.round(time / 60) + " minutes) " + "<i class='fa fa-eur' aria-hidden='true'></i> " + COST;
            } else if (MSG) {
                total_summary += '  <strong>' + MSG + '</strong>';
            }
            total_summary += '</div>';
            $("#summary").html(total_summary);

            map_zoom = map.getZoom();

            $("#loader").html('');
        } else {
            var statusText = getDirectionStatusText(status);
            //directionsDiv.innerHTML = "An error occurred - " + statusText;
        }

    });
}

// Show distance in different measurements
function showDistance(distance) {
    return Math.round(distance / 100) / 10 + " km (" + Math.round((distance * 0.621371192) / 100) / 10 + " miles)";
}

// Get the Map direction status message
function getDirectionStatusText(status) {
    switch (status) {
        case google.maps.DirectionsStatus.INVALID_REQUEST:
            return "Invalid request";
        case google.maps.DirectionsStatus.MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED:
            return "Maximum waypoints exceeded";
        case google.maps.DirectionsStatus.NOT_FOUND:
            return "Not found";
        case google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT:
            return "Over query limit";
        case google.maps.DirectionsStatus.REQUEST_DENIED:
            return "Request denied";
        case google.maps.DirectionsStatus.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            return "Unknown error";
        case google.maps.DirectionsStatus.ZERO_RESULTS:
            return "Zero results";
        default:
            return status;
    }
}


// Add More waypoints
function add_waypoint() {
    waypoint_container = '<div class="control-group ">';
    waypoint_container += '  <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Journey Start From :</label>';
    waypoint_container += '  <div class="controls">';
    waypoint_container += '      <input type="text" id="toWaypoints" name="toWaypoints[]" class="input-xlarge" value="">';
    waypoint_container += '      &nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="return add_waypoint();">Add Waypoints</a>';
    waypoint_container += '      &nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="return remove_waypoint(this);">Remove</a>';
    waypoint_container += '  </div>';
    waypoint_container += '</div>';

    $('.destination-container').before(waypoint_container);

    $('[name=toWaypoints\\[\\]]').each(function() {
        apply_autocomplete($(this)[0]);
    });

    return false;
}

// Remove waypoint
function remove_waypoint(obj) {
    $(obj).parent().parent().remove();
    return false;
}
```

How it should work: after clicking "Make calculations" it should open a new tab with final price and another textboxes with different variables. But it is not happening. I have no idea what is wrong with that code.

I guess it may be a problems with Google API (because this one I guess is just for tests and probably may have some restrictions).

PS. By the way, I can even see the "loading" but after this nothing happens.

Comment: Please include all code relevant to the question, in the question it self. StackSnippits, the `<>` button in the editor provides functionality like jsfiddle. Providing a [MCVE] is always a good start to helping us solve your problem. Nothing in the code you have provided in the question would open a tab

Comment: I know. But I have no idea which piece of code is not working, because I dont have any errors. Thats a problem

Comment: F12 console shows errors

Comment: Your code is not wrong! Try to put the contend of yours scripts and css in the html.

Comment: Do you mean insert all the codes inside of html?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the request to an insecure script from http://rustakso.com/codecanCalc/js/bootstrap.min.js

Use https or another host with it. Or put the code into html.

But You code works fine! Look it! [image: Look]

Comment: I just uploaded this files on my server, so I can share them. The problem is that even if I am trying to use them from safe place nothing happens. I dont know why. After clicking this "Make calculation" button new textboxes should appear, but nothing happens. In my code I have this references: `<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>`

Comment: so, if want your form appear try this >> $("#formdiv").show(); // on line 362

Comment: Yeah, now it works, but like... Half, I guess. There is also should be a "Total Distance" textbox.